# How to create a triangle/arrow shape with Border (pointing right)

Tags: html, css

I need to create the following image in HTML/CSS Only:

[image]

I've been testing and I've been able to create the right box with an arrow but the arrow is on the top rather then the side (you can see in the fiddle link):

http://jsfiddle.net/130mko3w/

The code that is putting the arrow on the top is as follows:

```
.arrow_box:after, .arrow_box:before {
    border: 13px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    left: 90%;
    bottom:100%;
}

.arrow_box:after {
    border-bottom-color: #fafafa;
    border-width: 14px;
    margin-left: -24px;
}

.arrow_box:before {
    border-bottom-color: #999;
    border-width: 15px;
    margin-left: -25px;
}
```

Would someone be able to assist me in moving the arrow to the right. Note: I've found if I change the Border-bottom-color to border-right-color the arrow goes to the side but the triangle is pointing in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use border radius and ::after, ::before pseudo-elements for the triangle shape:

```css
.arrow_box {
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  z-index: 99;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6), 0 4px 2px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) 0, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
  margin-top: 3em;
  margin-left: .75em;
  margin-right: .75em;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  width: 340px;
  height: 160px;
}

.arrow_box:after,
.arrow_box:before {
  border: 14px solid transparent;
  border-left-color: #f2f2f2;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: 100%;
  top: 15px;
}

.arrow_box:before {
  border-left-color: #aaa;
  border-width: 16px;
  margin-top: -2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow_box"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/130mko3w/

```
.arrow_box:after, .arrow_box:before {
border: 13px solid transparent;
position: absolute;
content: '';
left: 107%;
bottom: 60%;
}
.arrow_box:after {
border-left-color: #eee;
border-width: 14px;
margin-left: -24px;
}
.arrow_box:before {
border-left-color: #aaa;
border-width: 16px;
margin-left: -24px;
top: 34px;
}
```